How to get item in Text Based Game?
I have been trying to come up with the code to add an item to my inventory in my text based game but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. Here is my current code:
rooms = {
    'Entrance': {'west': 'Catacombs A', 'north': 'Main Hall'},
    'Catacombs A': {'east': 'Entrance', 'item': 'Lesser Artifact'},
    'Main Hall': {'north': 'Great Hall', 'east': 'Catacombs B', 'south': 'Entrance', 'west': 'Necron Tomb',
                  'item': 'Dog Tags'},
    'Necron Tomb': {'east': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'Supplies'},
    'Catacombs B': {'west': 'Main Hall', 'north': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Lesser Artifact'},
    'Storage Room': {'south': 'Catacombs B', 'item': 'Supplies'},
    'Great Hall': {'east': 'Repair Hub', 'south': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'Dog Tags'},
    'Repair Hub': {'west': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Necron Lord'}  # Villain
}

current_room = 'Entrance'
inventory = []

print('You are a member of a squad of Ultramarines that has been tasked with retrieving 6 items from a '
      'Necron facility on the orbiting planet before reaching the Necron Lord. You and your brothers breach the entrance, which way do you go first?')


def move_rooms(current_room, directions):
    current_room = rooms[current_room]
    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return new_room


while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    directions = input('Enter a direction: north, east, south, west, get item, or exit.')
    if directions in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions)
    if directions == 'exit':
        print('You have failed the Emperor and your brothers...')
        break
    elif directions not in rooms[current_room]:
        print('You cannot go that way.')


I tried making a define function for getting an item by doing
def get_item(item, inventory):
    if item in current_room:
        inventory.append(item[current_room])
        return inventory

Python gave me an error and asked to define item even though it is in my rooms dictionary. I am very new to python so I am struggling a lot, any help would be appreciated!

look at your get_item def. You're passing in an item, then you check if that item is in current_room, then you add... what? What is item[current_room]? What is item? Is it a dictionary with separate keys for each room? Please [edit] your post to show one block of code that simply includes the (not working) call to get_item.

So I've been experimenting with this and i think i may have found a method that will work. I made a function that takes the currentroom, and your inventory. It will search the dictionary of that room to see if it has an item and if it does it will append it to the inventory table. The code is as follows:
rooms = {
'Entrance': {'west': 'Catacombs A', 'north': 'Main Hall'},
'Catacombs A': {'east': 'Entrance', 'item': 'Lesser Artifact'},
'Main Hall': {'north': 'Great Hall', 'east': 'Catacombs B', 'south': 'Entrance', 'west': 'Necron Tomb',
              'item': 'Dog Tags'},
'Necron Tomb': {'east': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'Supplies'},
'Catacombs B': {'west': 'Main Hall', 'north': 'Storage Room', 'item': 'Lesser Artifact'},
'Storage Room': {'south': 'Catacombs B', 'item': 'Supplies'},
'Great Hall': {'east': 'Repair Hub', 'south': 'Main Hall', 'item': 'Dog Tags'},
'Repair Hub': {'west': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Necron Lord'}  # Villain
}

current_room = 'Storage Room'
inventory = []
items = 'item'

def get_item(currentroom, inventory):
    roomtosearch = rooms[currentroom]
    if items in roomtosearch:
        found = roomtosearch[items]
        inventory.append(found)
    else:
        print('No such item exists')

get_item(current_room, inventory)
print(inventory)

you can add an if statement in your while true loop that when given that direction input it if its "item" it will call the get_item() function searching that room for an item. Ex:
while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    directions = input('Enter a direction: north, east, south, west, get item, or exit.')
    if directions in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions)
    if directions == 'exit':
        print('You have failed the Emperor and your brothers...')
        break
    if directions == 'item':
        get_item(current_room, inventory)
    elif directions not in rooms[current_room]:
        print('You cannot go that way.')

I saw your comment and i did some more testing and i realized that the sequence is messed up, because it searches for if item is in the room which it is, and it checks for that before it runs the get_item function it will set the current room to the item making the get_item throw an error. The solution to this is to rephrase the get_item statement to check before the moveroom one and if it the get_item check is true it wont run the moveroom function. My new code is as follows:
while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    directions = input('Enter a direction: north, east, south, west, get item, or exit.')
    if directions == 'item':
        print(current_room)
        get_item(current_room, inventory)
    elif directions in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions)
        print(current_room)
    elif directions == 'exit':
        print('You have failed the Emperor and your brothers...')
        break
    elif directions not in rooms[current_room]:
        print('You cannot go that way.')


So I tried your code but when inputting 'item' into the command it gives me an error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tronb\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\TextBasedGame.py", line 50, in 
get_item(current_room, inventory)
File "C:\Users\tronb\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\TextBasedGame.py", line 28, in get_item
roomtosearch = rooms[current_room]
~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Dog Tags'

I saw your comment and added a new section of code and a new paragraph at the end. Try that instead

Yes! That seemed to work, thank you so much, Ive been having trouble with the get item part for the past few days. One day I'll hopefully be able to do all this without asking for help.

Check if you are giving the right input for the get_item function and if the variable item is given as a list. I think items is being used as a string inside the “rooms” dictionary, but it is being indexed as a list in your define function. (problem is in italics)
def get_item(item, inventory):
    if item in current_room:
        inventory.append(*item[current_room]*)
        return inventory

